# Multiple associations in same table with multiple potential foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to do some seemingly simple associations:

```
class OrderWizard < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :buyer_wizard,     :class_name => MiniWizard.name
  belongs_to :seller_wizard,    :class_name => MiniWizard.name
end

class MiniWizard < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :order_wizard, :foreign_key = '????' # Could be buyer_wizard_id or seller_wizard_id

   def is_buyer_wizard?
     ??
   end

   def is_seller_wizard?
     ??
   end
end
```

1. An associated MiniWizard needs to know who is connecting to it.  Assuming has_many :through best way to go?  If so, how would the models look?
2. A MiniWizard instance needs to know if it's a buyer or seller.  Stuck on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually probably want two associations, for example, something like this might represent the relationships more accurately:

```
class MiniWizard < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :bought_order_wizard, :foreign_key => 'buyer_wizard_id', :class_name => 'MiniWizard'
   has_one :sold_order_wizard, :foreign_key => 'seller_wizard_id', :class_name => 'MiniWizard'

  def order_wizard
    bought_order_wizard || sold_order_wizard
  end

  def is_buyer_wizard?
    !bought_order_wizard.nil?
  end

  def is_seller_wizard?
    !sold_order_wizard.nil?
  end
end
```

Comment: But a MiniWizard instance will have one and only one order_wizard.  So why has_many?

Comment: I updated my answer to work for the has_one case. It doesn't really matter how you define the relationship, since both has_one and has_many will work depending on your use case, the point is that you have two relationships - one for each foreign key, not a single relationship.

Comment: .. and if I just wanted the order_wizard could would the added method work?

Comment: I updated the code with the equivalent of an order_wizard function and a check for is_buyer_wizard? and is_seller_wizard?.

Comment: I like it, but it's pretty ugly.  What am I doing that makes it feel like it's not the "Rails Way" (tm)

Comment: The problem is that you are taking a two model relationships and you are trying to create a single one out of them. What I would recommend is removing those functions (order_wizard, is_buyer_wizard? and is_seller_wizard?) and structuring your code to only use bought_order_wizard and sold_order_wizard. That part of the code is pretty and simple and it models what is actually happening in the database.